# How do I use jq to convert this object to this object?

Tags: arrays, jq

I'm trying to convert the object below using jq:

```json
{
    "locals": {
      "products": {
        "core-tower1": {
          "core-tower1-product-a": ["dev"],
          "core-tower1-product-b": ["dev", "prod"]
        },
        "core-tower2": {
          "core-tower2-product-a": ["pol", "onb"],
          "core-tower2-product-a": ["dev", "prod"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

to this

```json
{
        "core-tower1": [
          "core-tower1-product-a",
          "core-tower1-product-b"
        ]
        "core-tower2": [
          "core-tower2-product-a",
          "core-tower2-product-a"
        ]
      }
```

I tried this it as seen below:

```bash
jq {'(.locals.products|keys[])':'.locals.products|.[]|keys'}
```

but I got the result below:

```json
 {
        "core-tower1": [
          "core-tower1-product-a",
          "core-tower1-product-b"
        ]
        "core-tower1": [
          "core-tower2-product-a",
          "core-tower2-product-a"
        ]
      }
 {
        "core-tower2": [
          "core-tower1-product-a",
          "core-tower1-product-b"
        ]
        "core-tower2": [
          "core-tower2-product-a",
          "core-tower2-product-a"
        ]
      }
```

Let me know if there's a different way to do this or is jq the best approach here.

Comment: jq '.locals.products | to_entries | map({key: .key, value: [.value | keys]}) | from_entries'
use to_entires and map function in jq

Comment: @hasan, when you have `to_entries | ... | from_entries`, think about `with_entries`: `jq '.locals.products | with_entries({key, value: (.value|keys)})'`

Comment: Or even just `.locals.products | with_entries(.value |= keys)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with [`reduce`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce):

```bash
jq '
    .locals.products | to_entries
    | reduce .[] as $e (
        {}; . + { ($e.key): $e.value | keys }
    )
'
```

Notice that  both keys in `core-tower2` are identical, which leads to jq dropping the duplicate, resulting in

```json
{
  "core-tower1": [
    "core-tower1-product-a",
    "core-tower1-product-b"
  ],
  "core-tower2": [
    "core-tower2-product-a"
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works. what if I want to modify the output as:

`{"locals": {
      "products": {{
  "core-tower1": [
    "core-tower1-product-a",
    "core-tower1-product-b"
  ],
  "core-tower2": [
    "core-tower2-product-a"
  ]
}}
`

Comment: @Owen You'd replace the first `|` with `|=` and wrap everything to the right of it in parentheses.

Comment: thank you, sir. you are excellent at this.

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is with the swallowed duplicate keys, then consider using the `--stream` option which provides the input document "in pieces", so that the parts can be processed before any duplicate keys can collapse. This approach, however, may need more insight into the logical structuring of your document, so let me assume here that you want to generally cut off the first two levels `.[2:]`, build the values array from the level directly above the scalars/leaves (i.e. the second-to-last level, `-2`), and just copy over all levels in between:

```bash
jq --stream -n '
  reduce (inputs | select(has(1))[0][2:]) as $p ({};
    setpath($p | .[-2:] |= [last]; $p[-2])
  )
'
```

```json
{
  "core-tower1": [
    "core-tower1-product-b",
    "core-tower1-product-b"
  ],
  "core-tower2": [
    "core-tower2-product-a",
    "core-tower2-product-a"
  ]
}
```